# Java Class for retrieving Large String from Oracle_db of LOB dataType

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle10g

Have an oracle database with one of its fields set to LOB(large objects) data type. When I  run a select statement
, this error gets thrown:

```
ERROR:
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 10228,      
maximum: 4000)
```

This size of the string(which are logs) inside each tuble is 10228 more than the Max capacity of the buffer. I need to fetch the entire string.

I was able to come up with this temp solution:

```
Select  dbms_lob.substr( BLOB_FieldName, 4000, 1 ) 
from Database name Where [Condition];
```

with this query, I was able to get the first 4000 bytes of the string, which is great, but we need the entire string.

And then after reading about utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 I tried the following

```
Select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( dbms_lob.substr( BLOB_fieldName, 19000, 1 ) ) 
from[dbname];
```

I used  utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 because I read somewhere online that [Varchar2] datatype can hold up to 32k byte and thought of casting [LOB] data type to Varchar2 , but it did not work.

FYI,
We are  restricted from using PL/SQL.
Environment is linux, rhel.

I need some guidance on how to go about doing this.

Comment: There is no `LOB` datatype in Oracle. There is either `BLOB`, `CLOB` or (the deprecated) `LONG` datatype. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any up-to-date driver, you can just select `CLOB` columns and call ResultSet.getString() to obtain the value. No need for any special treatment like `dbms_lob()`.

The 11.x drivers are definitely capable of doing that, not sure about the outdated 10.x drivers though.

If the driver is too old and upgrading is not an option, you still don't need any special treatment in your SQL statement, just process the `CLOB` from the ResultSet using `getCharacterStream()` - that even works with 9.x drivers.

Something like:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select clob_column from table_name name ...");
Reader in = rs.getCharacterStream(1);
String clobValue = null;
if (!rs.wasNull())
{
   // process whatever the Reader returns, e.g. using Apache Commons IO
   clobValue = IOUtils.toString(in);
}
in.close();
```

With a current driver, you'd just do:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select clob_column from table_name name ...");
String clobValue = rs.getString(1);
```

Btw: Oracle 10 is pretty outdated, you should really think about upgrading.

Comment: @StackUnderFlow: my example assumes that you know the basics on how to connect to a database using JDBC and run a SQL query. If that is not the case I recommend a JDBC tutorial, e.g. the one from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response  @a_horse_with_no_name . I do know the basics of JDBC, my problem was doing the work from linux environemnt which I am not so used to .Anyways thanks for your time and efforts your code worked like a champ