# Oracle SQL display blob contents greater than varchar2 max limit

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I display the rest of the xml for this sql query since varchar2 is only limited to 2000?

Column msg is a blob which contains compressed XML
Each row will have different msg length ranging from 500 to 6000 bytes as least

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(utl_compress.lz_uncompress(xml.msg),2000,1)) as XML_Msg from xml_table xml;
```

This could be a possible solution [Convert Blob to Varchar datatype](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_varchar_datatype.htm) but I don't know what it would do to my database.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle the MAX you can retrieve from blob data type is 4000 bytes , below is statment that can do the job. I ran into the same problem two weeks ago , please refer to my post for more details. [Java Class for retrieving Large String from Oracle_db of LOB dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239328/java-class-for-retrieving-large-string-from-oracle-db-of-lob-datatype)

```
   Select  dbms_lob.substr( BLOB_FieldName, 4000, 1 ) 
   from Database name Where [Condition];
```

Comment: Hi StackUnderFlow, the blob column doesn't have a fix length because there are different XML strings that I need to extract some are more than 4000 bytes others well below 500. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @dimas   with this SQL statement you will be able to retrieve the first 4000 byte of the string . this can be temp solution, If you want the string in its entirety I belive you will have to use "ResultSet" as descibed on my post.

Comment: Am not doing this in java but in SQL Developer ;)

Comment: In my case the strings retrived were logs , with "resultset and if (!rs.wasNull())" it will iterate till it hits null retriving the entire string . below is the statment that does the job.        ResultSet          rs = statement.executeQuery("Select clob_column from table_name name   ...");
             Reader in = rs.getCharacterStream(1);
            String clobValue = null;
if (!rs.wasNull())
{
   // process whatever the Reader returns, e.g. using Apache Commons IO
   clobValue = IOUtils.toString(in);
}
in.close();

Comment: From what I know it is impossible to do it solely in SQL developer, since the size of the buffer in Oracle platform is limited to 4000 bytes.

Comment: I've seen some solutions that uses loops and temporary variables to do this. But am no expert in sql so I dare not use not them unless I understand all of the things they're doing.

Comment: @dimas I believe it is feasible ,but you have to use SQLplus, not plain SQL..Where I work we are not allowed to use SQL plus, So i had to do it by writing a java class with JDBC connection. Here is a link http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: uhmm... thanks for the link but that is not sqlplus just pure Java code using JDBC. SQLPlus is just Oracle SQL but is mostly accesssible in Linux console (Windows?).